# Toggle function: Remember the position

Tags: php, javascript, toggle

I used the function toggle I would like that if I refresh the page, it remember the position of the toggle.
I try to use the session but I can't find the way to update the session (when the user want to see more or less).

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function toggle(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {    
            var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
        var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="more.png"">';
        }else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="less.png">';        
        }
    }

</script>   

<?php 
if(empty($_SESSION["toggle"])){
 $_SESSION["toggle"] = 'show'; 
}?>

<a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img src="lesss.png"></a>Title

<?php if($_SESSION["toggle"] == 'show'){ ?>
  <div id="contentDivImg" style="display: block;">
<?php 
   $_SESSION["toggle"] = 'hidden'; 
 } 
 if($_SESSION["toggle"] == 'hidden'){ ?>
   <div id="contentDivImg" style="display: none">
<?php $_SESSION["toggle"] = 'show'; 
 } ?>
Try Show & hide
</div>
```

Comment: use JavaScript cookie...

Comment: He's right, off the top of my head -- JavaScript Cookies sounds like the way to go on this one.

Comment: i try to use cookie but i get same kind of problem because it still show me the same when i refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second @Akam and @ChaseMoskal suggesting you use JavaScript for this.

It should be as simple as

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function toggle(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {    
        var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
        var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            // Also set the toggle cookie on toggle
            document.cookie = 'toggle=hide'
            ele.style.display = "none";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="more.png"">';
        }else {
            // Also set the toggle cookie on toggle
            document.cookie = 'toggle=show'
            ele.style.display = "block";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="less.png">';        
        }
    }
</script>   
</head>
<body>

<a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img src="lesss.png"></a>Title


<div id="contentDivImg" style="display:block">Try Show & hide</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // Run at the end of the body so that the dom is ready for us
    // Dont beleave me? reade this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/G-7Ltdavy0E
    (function(){
        // Get the cookie we want to check using a fancy-pants regex
        var cookie = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)toggle\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
        if (cookie === 'hide')
            // If the cookie says hide, just use the toggle function
            // The user wont see the change because were still running way before readystate complete
            toggle('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');
    }())
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This uses document.cookie to set a toggle cookie to either show or hide.
If the toggle cookie is hide then the toggle function gets called before the page finishes loading.

---

Note that while this will work when the file is served from a remote server (or localhost) over http(s), it won't work if the file is retrieved using the file: protocol because cookies are associated with a domain.

If you want to learn more about using cookies in JavaScript or just want to copy and past some useful functions (and even a small framework) check out the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie)

Comment: Hi thanks! I read what you give me and now I try to have more than 1 toggle. My problem is here:     
if (cookie === 'hide')      
     toggle('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');
If I put a new toggle how the cookie will know which toggle to hide?

Comment: You could name your cookies based on the `id`s of the element to be toggled. E.g. `ele.id + '-toggle'`. For checking the values of dirrerent cookies, I would **seriously recommend this [small cookie framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support)** that provides a `getItem()` method for checking values, as well as `setItem()` `removeItem()` and `hasItem()`. If you like I can rewrite the question to make use of these functions and support multiple toggled elements

Comment: hi thanks for your help. I try different things but it doesn't work very well. most of the time if the last toggle I have do something the others will follow and then works well, it's a little strange for me